# how to do this boxes in bbc website

Tags: language-agnostic

in this web site

http://www.bbc.co.uk/

or in the end of this site
http://www.cliprz-php.com/

more boxes like (travel , radio , sport , tv channel)

i need to make this css boxes in my website and insert news into it

how can i do this or any tutorial

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot more than just CSS going on there. A majority of that is JavaScript mouse events.

Comment: ok i now that but i dont need all boxes effect i just want to know
how to make simple box and insert some news in it

Comment: You would probably want to use something similar to the "Stacked Columns" layout on http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-multi-column-liquid-layouts